# how to bind dependent templates by using knockoutjs template binding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have list of attributes that need to be rendered as different form elements, depending on their `FieldControlId`:

```
<script type="text/html" id="elc-field">
<div class="grid_8">
    <span data-bind="text: FieldDisplayName"></span>
</div>
<div data-bind="if: FieldControlId == 1 " class="grid_8">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: FieldValue , attr: { 'id': FieldId  }" />
</div>
 <div data-bind="if: FieldControlId == 2 " class="grid_8">
     <input data-bind="value: FieldValue , numeric: number , attr: { 'id': FieldId  }" />
</div>
<div data-bind="if: FieldControlId == 3 " class="grid_8">
    <select data-bind="combobox:FieldValue , attr: { 'id': FieldId }"></select>
</div>
<div data-bind="if: FieldControlId == 4 " class="grid_8">
    <input class="dt" data-bind="attr: { 'id': FieldId } ,  value: FieldValue, datepicker:true" />
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
```

However, I want some controls to also depend on another attributes' selected value. For example, a `<select>` defining the contents of a second `<select>`, which in turn defines a third one.

Comment: what exactly you trying to say .i am unable to relate to the code you given and things you said so for i.e drop-down etc .

Comment: I tried to rephrase your question as I understood it, in order to make it easier to comprehend — I hope that I got the intent of your question right. Also, please include the view model that is bound to your markup in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a computed property of your model that can determine your template.  Such as:

```
var model = function(){
    var self = this;

    self.NeedsSpecialTemplate = ko.observable(true);

    self.SpecialText = ko.observable('Special Text');

    self.Template = ko.computed(function(){
        if(self.NeedsSpecialTemplate()){
            return 'special-template'
        }
        return 'normal-template'
    })
}
```

and then in your markup use:

```
<div data-bind="template:{ name: Template() }"></div>
```

and the template examples:

```
<script type="text/html" id="normal-template">
    <div>Normal Stuff</div>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="special-template">
    <div>Special Stuff</div>
    <div data-bind="text: SpecialText"></div>
</script>
```

And from there the send level template could nest additional templates driven from additional properties.